Flutter ReorderableListView is not working perfectly in a scrollable parent
In Flutter when i am wrapping my ReorderableListView within ListView or Column with SingleChildScrollView, it is getting rendered but in the case when the height of the total number of items are exceeding the screenheight, when I am dragging one item to the edge of the screen the reorderable listview is not autoscrolling.
But it works fine when there is no scrollable parent it autoscrolls when i am dragging my item to the edge of the screen
This is a minimalistic code that explains my issue
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _items = List.generate(25, (index) => index.toString());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 48 * 25,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 88),
            child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    key: ValueKey(_items[index]),
                    title: Text(_items[index]),
                  );
                },
                onReorder: (int oldindex, int newindex) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (newindex > oldindex) {
                      newindex -= 1;
                    }
                    final item = _items.removeAt(oldindex);
                    _items.insert(newindex, item);
                  });
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have tried using nestedscrollview, primaryscrollcontroller but I didnt get any good results

Look at the following structure:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // Your height
                            child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                                     physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                     shrinkWrap: true,
                                     ......
                             )
                             ),
                        Text('Does it work?')
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

Hope it helps you.

I have tried that it isn't working. If I add neverscrollable to parent container the reorderablelistview doesn't scroll and if I add it it to the reorderablelistview nothing changes. And apart from that I need the scrollable physics as I am applying scrollview on the whole page

@KartikeyMahawar ok, i will update

Thanks for helping, it works!
I debugged it for a bit the issue is that the reorderable widget takes the start and end of container as offsets on which it starts scrolling even if the height of the container is more than that of screen. So if we didn't mention any height or gave a height bigger than screen or even give a margin, it doesn't work

@KartikeyMahawar , good for you.

This ClampingScrollPhysics() helped for me:
ReorderableListView(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // add this line
 buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
 onReorder: _onReorder,
 children: [ 
  // Your children widget
 ],
),

